# How to create a configurable system in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

The scenario is: the company where I work need to ship a product which it's features are defined by the contract.

- One client need a full system, with all the report capabilities and stuff
- Other client (or more correctly, a product) need only the data from the database to be displayed and downloadable, and many other product scenarios may rise in the near future.

While  Instead of creating different systems and adding and correcting bugs to each, it seems reasonable to be able to set what will or not be shipped to client. I'm trying to find an elegant solution to that ... my Controllers and my Models will remain exactly the same, but my Views will change big time.

Any thoughts on how to make that work?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if i understood correctly. You have two different feature sets and want to join them in a single codebase capable of both? At what level they are similar?

I'd work on maintaining a single codebase for the data and logic layer [(More Here)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture), and depdending on the amount of differences on the presentation layer do one of the following:

- Create another asp.net mvc3 project that uses my "shared" libs from other tiers
- Create all the functionality on one single asp.net mvc3 project and then working on the routes to enable/disable certain stuff, if you want you can also do this on some configuration files, thus not requiring a specific build for each client.

Without more details i can't say much.

Comment: Well, the context is Power Generation, meaning the system displays data about the Power Plants and its generating units, which are gathered by our piece of hardware. The system I've been working in displays management data, such as commercial and maintenance data, and also images of the plants, and also the data gathered by the product in lists and charts. Now I need a product that doesn't display management data, and I don't know how to do it the right way.

Comment: Well, you can use the same exact logic you have implemented right now plus adding anything that you need for the second product, and simply disable what you don't before shipping (see answers for suggestions). You have implementation-related problems?

Comment: I wanted to do something like when you create the basic menu (the one which comes with the sample) that an if in the cshtml determines whether something should or should not be displayed (by making an if). I don't want, for instance, to create a ViewBag item in each controller action to send this data, but this data to be part of the system. At least that's one way I can see it working.

Comment: I would not operate at view level regardless of the level of integration, but that's how some modular/dynamic portal (see ibm websphere) do it anyway: they read some configuration from the db and depending on what is set to active they render specific partials on the view. A valid approach would be to develop a plugin system, but this can easily become difficult. It would help to see some code example in your question.

Answer (score 0):

When only your views are different per configuration, maybe a solution is to create subfolders in each view folder. For example `Views/Home/Config1/Index.cshtml`, `Views/Home/Config2/Index.cshtml`, etc.
By overriding the `View` (and `PartialView`) function in a controller (e.g. create a `MasterController`) you could automatically switch to the right subfolder in a view directory.

Comment: But it doesn't seem elegant. I mean, for each different setup I would create another View folder for each controller. In the end, I would end up with a lot of folders.

Comment: True, this only works when you have for example 3 fixed configurations, not a configuration per customer.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you put this information in the database(like, wich views the user has access to) and build your menus based on this information?

This would mean that your entire menu structure will become dynamic(so this would change a lot, as i imagine your menus are static). But It'd solve your problem, i guess..

Comment: That's exactly what I don't want. I want something that can be configurable, like the wiki applications or Mantis Bug Tracker. If I was to create different roles, I would simply use the annotation provided to do that, which would be enough.